# Replace last item in a Views grid of images

Tags: views, media, files

let's say I have 1000 image files on my server and I am paging the 10 newest (2 rows with 5 images each) on my frontpage in a views block, formatted as a 'grid'. The settings of my view are:

Format: Grid, Show: Fields, File: Rendered, and then filter by File: Type (= Image) and sort by File: Upload date

Instead of adding a "see more" link I would like to replace the 10th image with a "see more" **button** which has the same format as the images. Is there a way to only render a grid of **9** images and tell views which image to use as the 10th?

Comment: you can set paging to 9 newest and add footer with your custom image and link then style it with css

Comment: can i actually move it into the grid with css? well, optically? or will it stay below the grid?

Comment: it will not be in the grid as HTML; the footer should be positioned in css to look as if it in the grid

Comment: I see what you're saying. Thank you, I will give it a try. But is there no way to actually get it into the grid in html from the Views UI? I will be using responsive designs and I don't wanna mess with CSS in each case individually.

Answer (score 1):

> But is there no way to actually get it into the grid in html from the
>   Views UI?

As I can see thare is no way for that in views UI.

But here are possible custom solutions:

**Solution1**

1. Add "more link" in PAGER section. Than specify link in 'Link
   display' section under ADVANCED.
2. Style your link with css

**Solution2**
Add new views row in `[hook_views_pre_render][1]`

**Solution3**
Add new views row in custon views `template`